# Can anyone explain how reinterpret cast is working in this code

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

read the following program which is using
reinterpret_cast.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
   public:
      A() : m_i(0) { }
   protected:
      int m_i;
};

class B
{
   public:
      B() : m_d(0.0) { }

   protected:
      double m_d;
};

class C : public A , public B
{
   public:
      C() : m_c('a') { }
   private:
      char m_c;
};

int main()
{
   C c;
   A *pa = &c;
   B *pb = &c;

   bool z = (reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa) == reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb));
   std::cout << z;
   return 0;
}
```

After running this program it prints 0, can anyone explain
why z is coming false in this program??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone explain how reinterpret cast is working in this code

`reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa)` evaluates to a pointer of type `char*` whose numerical value is the same as that of `pa`. Use of:

```
bool z = (pa == pb);
```

leads to a compiler error since `A` and `B` are not directly related. Use of

```
bool z = (reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa) == reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb));
```

allows you to compare the numerical values of `pa` and `pb`.

> After running this program it prints 0, can anyone explain why z is coming false in this program??

The numerical values of `pa` and `pb` are not same. Hence, the result. You can use:

```
cout << "pa: " << std::hex << (void*)pa << std::endl;
cout << "pb: " << std::hex << (void*)pb << std::endl;
```

to print those values and convince yourself that they are not same.

If you look at the memory layout of a `C`, it looks something like:

```
+------+
|  m_i |     // The A sub-object
+------+
|  m_d |     // The B sub-object
+------+
|  m_c |     
+------+
```

When you use

```
C c;
A* pa = &c;
B* pb = &c;
```

`pa` points to the `A` sub-object of `C` and `pb` points to the `B` sub-object of `C`. As you can see from the picture, there is an offset between the `A` sub-object and the `B` sub-object. Hence, the numerical values of `pa` and `pb` are different. The most likely differ by `sizeof(m_i)`.

Comment: @R Sahu  why the value of pa and pb are coming different.  They are having the same value  address of c (&c)

Comment: I don't think `bool z = (pa == pb);` would compile, as `A` and `B` do not derive from each other and so an `A*` pointer cannot be directly compared to a `B*` pointer without casting them to a common data type, in this case `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

reinterpret_cast is the same as static_cast here.  reinterpret_cast happens at run time while static_cast happens at compile time.  It makes no difference in this case, but it would make a difference if the cast were applied to the object c.

```
A* pa = &reinterpret_cast<A&>(c); 
B* pb = &reinterpret_cast<B&>(c);
```

would make pa and pb the same.  While what you wrote effectively does an *implicit* static cast:

```
A* pa = &static_cast<A&>(c); 
B* pb = &static_cast<B&>(c);
```

And since this makes pa and pb different, it doesn't matter that they are later "reinterpreted".